# Godex lable printing with c#

Tags: c#, printing, label, barcode-printing

I want to printing a label, but i cant.
I watched lot of video about this, but i cant find any solution.
Here is my code:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgktb.png)
I dont know what bool test do, because it never used. (I copied)

Anyone any idea?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update

I find a method, and it work.

I create a label with GoLabel program.
Important! Use only built-in text. After you done with the label, click the export button and it create a raw print code.

In the program repleace the desired text with [printext].Repleace() method.
Save the text to a txt file.
After, create a cmd string, and use this code:

```
 strCmdText = @"/C LPR -S " + ip + " -d -P raw toprinter.txt";
```

ip means the current printer IP address.

Finally, run it with cmd like this:

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
```

When the cmd app just pop up and close, you need to install windows SDK and move these files:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecAGk.png)

to:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64
```

this directory.

If you done with this, it will print your label.